# Multilingual content Migration

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have Multi-Language website, I need this website to migrate new Drupal website.

I can use [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module for export the content; however, I have a multi-language site, how should I handle those translation nodes ?

Comment: Is the "new" Drupal, Drupal 8 or another Drupal 7 website ? What type of translation are you using ? Node translation ?

Comment: I have used "internalization" module, and am going to migrate New Drupal 7 website

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to create an xml view of your content in each language and import it with feeds module and xpath. Or if it is easier for you, you can export to csv with views data export and import to your new drupal with feeds csv parser. It is much easier and more reliable as you have total control of your content. Though be careful with the delimiters if using csv. XML is safer.

Comment: is it possible to export multi language contents

Comment: Yes there is a Node translation filter. Another solution is to do it programmatically using the global $language  variable. And finally you can always check this old patch too: https://www.drupal.org/node/1330332

Comment: i have asked about content migration.. hope you not get my point

Comment: Explain it better and I can help you as I have migrated multilingual content many many times with feeds